# Reading a file byte by byte in Java

Tags: java, file

I am currently using this:

```
Path path = Paths.get("c:\test\test.txt");
byte[] all= Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

The problem with this is that I have to load the entire file in memory. My requirement is to read the file byte by byte, but in a manner like first 4 bytes mean X, next 16 bytes mean Y and use next 48 bytes for Z, etc.

Right now I am looping through all to do this.. My current code has a pointer which I am moving till `all.length` and using `Arrays.copyOfRange` to copy parts to other arrays for use. I am interested in knowing about `BufferedReaders` which reads a few bytes and then I can process them.

Comment: *"My current code has a pointer which I am moving..."* - so, show us the code. [Too late now that there's an answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c), but this question is incomplete. Java does have a great, native solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a data input and use the [`readFully(byte[]...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully(byte[])) method.

A quick way would be something like:

```
byte[] header = new byte[4];
byte[] name = new byte[16];
DataInput input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
input.readFully(header);
input.readFully(name);
input.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a doubt though. Can you please help me with http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122037/how-to-detect-if-bufferedinputstream-was-over-while-filling-an-array-in-java?

Comment: The code above is bound to be a problem. Why not use `DataInputStream.readFully()` which is the right tool for the job?